# failed_when with msg in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am trying to validate the result of a lookup done via dig, but I am receiving a error.
Could someone help me?

```
  - name: Simple A record (IPV4 address) lookup for {{ kubeapi_server }}
    debug: msg="{{ lookup('dig', '{{ kubeapi_server }}' )}}"
  - debug:
      msg:
      - "DNS A Record for {{ lookup('dig', '{{ kubeapi_server }}' )}}"
    failed_when: msg.stdout != ""
```

Output

```
TASK [0_test : debug] ******************************************************
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'msg.stdout != \"\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (msg.stdout != \"\"): 'msg' is undefined"}
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved it by simplying assigning the whole lookup to variable and then == to see if its empty.

````
      - name: Validate DNS record lookup for {{ kubeapi_server }}
        debug: msg="{{ lookup('dig', '{{ kubeapi_server }}' )}}"
        vars:
          variable: "{{ lookup('dig', '{{ kubeapi_server }}' )}}"
        failed_when: variable == ''
    ```
````

Comment: [Don’t compare to an empty string (E602)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/rules/default_rules.html#default-rules). Use *``failed_when: not variable``*

Comment: ahh. i like that. shall i edit my answer? you wanna post a new one?